# Why Firebase Database in Unity 2018 takes 35 Mb ipa File Build Size?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2018.  In My projects i makes the unity Build with Firebase  Database. For Normal Empty Build in unity 2018 takes  41 Mb.

Scripting Run time Version =net 4x equivalent
 API Compatibility Level= .net Standard 2.0

While i import Firebase.Database   the  empty Build size+ Firebase Database will take  71 Mb. Nearly 30 Mb is increasing in  my IPA build Size..

Firebase Auth+ Firebase Messaging  adds only 1 M.B.

So  i have to reduce build size under 100 Mb.

Why Firebase Database  adds 30 Mb. Is there any way to reduce the build size ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a Solution.I have update the version of Xcode 9.1 to 10.1 Now the Mb is Miraculously Reduced. to 11 mb.

Now the Empty Project  of unity 2018.2.13f1 + Xcode 10.1=11 mb.(ipa file size...

So Update your XCode to 10.1 ... you will see the miraculous size variation....

When i add Firebase database+empty project  + xcode 10.1 =23 Mb Only...

So there are lot of Miraculous change...

Try the above method... you will see the huge WOW in your mind.

Thanks